# How to show that the following equality holds for infimum?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In one of the book I read that the following equality holds

$$\inf_{\|u\|_2\leq 1} a^TP_iu=-\|a^TP_i\|_2.$$ How can we prove this equality? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do $P_i$ comes from ? Why not replacing it plainly by a generic vector $V$ ?

Comment: Use Cauchy Schwarz case of equality.

Comment: @JeanMarie I know that the Cauchy Schwarz inequality says that $v^Tu\leq \|v\|_2\|u\|_2$, but I do not know how to include infimum into this. Please help.

Comment: See my answer that use Cauchy-Schwartz without recourse to dual space. I wasn't aware of your question because (so I think) you had used JeanMarie instead of Jean Marie...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the definition of the dual norm. Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then its dual norm is defined as

$$
\|x\|_{*} = \sup_{\|u\|\leq 1}\langle x, u\rangle.
$$

The dual norm is also a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm, its dual coincides with it, that is, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$

$$
\|x\|_2 = \|x\|_{2,*} = \sup_{\|u\|_2\leq 1}x^\top u = -\inf_{\|u\|_2\leq 1} -x^\top u.
$$

In your case,

\begin{align}
\inf_{\|u\|_2 \leq 1} a^\top P_i u 
{}={}&
 -\sup_{\|u\|_2 \leq 1} -(P_i^\top a)^\top u
\\
{}={}&
-\|-P_i^\top a\|_2
\\
{}={}& - \|P_i^\top a\|_2.
\end{align}

I'm not sure why you have $\|-a^\top P_i\|_2$, but I assumed here that $a,u\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $P_i\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not necessitate to use the dual norm.

First of all, let us slightly simplify the issue ; in your expression :

$$\inf_{\|u\|_2\leq 1} a^TP_iu=-\|a^TP_i\|_2,$$

let us set  $V=P_i^Ta$. We have thus to prove that :

$$\inf_{\|u\|_2\leq 1} \underbrace{V^Tu}_{\langle V,u \rangle}=-\|V\|_2.$$

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says that

$$|\langle V,u \rangle| \leq \|V \|_2 \|u \|_2 \ \text{with equality iff} \ V=\lambda u$$

Or equivalently :

$$-\|V \|_2 \|u \|_2 \color{red}{\leq} \langle V,u \rangle  \leq \|V \|_2 \|u \|_2 \ \text{with equality iff} \ V=\lambda u$$

(we will use only the left inequality).

Let us now consider $u=-\dfrac{V}{\|V\|_2}$ ; its norm is $1$ and it is proportional to $V$, thus the minimum is reached, and we obtain the looked for result :

$$-\|V \|_2 \times 1 \color{red}{=} \inf_{\|u\|_2\leq 1} \langle V,u \rangle.$$